# approximate floor function with a linear one

Tags: laplace-transform, ceiling-and-floor-functions, linearization

How to linearize floor function in form of transfer function?

suppose you have input and out put to the floor function as r and y.

`y = floor(r)`,

I want to replace floor or approximate it with a linear transfer function, so I can have it as:

```
G = y/r;
```

where G has the same functionality as floor.

G can be a  linear Laplace transformation of floor function, as you know a nonlinear Laplace transformation of floor function would be,

```
e^(-s)/s(1-e^(-s))
```

what about linear transformation?

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Transfer function? Do you mean $G=y/r$ is supposed to hold in the Laplace transform domain?

Comment: Yes, a linear transfer function (linear Laplace transform of this).

Answer (score 0):

The Laplace transform of it has been derived from [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553789/laplace-transform-of-floorx).

> [LaplaceTransform[Floor[t], t, s]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=laplace%20transform%20of%20floor%28t%29)
>
> [image]
>
> [Plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B1%2F%28%28E%5Ez%20-%201%29%20z%29%2C%20%7Bz%2C%20-10%20-%2010%20I%2C%2010%20%2B%2010%20I%7D%5D)
>
> [image]

---

To get better asymptotic approximation, we're going to use  [Padé approximant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant).
For better intuitive explanation, see the question titled: [The unreasonable effectiveness of Padé approximation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122539/the-unreasonable-effectiveness-of-pad%C3%A9-approximation).

I'll compute it with WolframAlpha.

---

Its first-order approximation will be:

> [PadeApproximant[LaplaceTransform[Floor[t], t, s], {s, 1, 1}]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=PadeApproximant%5BLaplaceTransform%5BFloor%5Bt%5D%2C%20t%2C%20s%5D%2C%20%7Bs%2C%201%2C%201%7D%5D)
>
> [image]
>
> [Plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B%28-2%20%2B%207%20E%20-%203%20E%20z%29%2F%28-%28E%20%281%20%2B%20E%29%29%20%2B%20%282%20-%205%20E%20%2B%205%20E%5E2%29%20z%29%2C%20%7Bz%2C%20-10%20-%2010%20I%2C%2010%20%2B%2010%20I%7D%5D)
>
> [image]

---

Its second-order approximation will be:

> [PadeApproximant[LaplaceTransform[Floor[t], t, s], {s, 2, 2}]](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=PadeApproximant%5BLaplaceTransform%5BFloor%5Bt%5D%2C%20t%2C%20s%5D%2C%20%7Bs%2C%202%2C%202%7D%5D)
>
> [image]
>
> [Plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Plot%5B%287%20E%5E2%20z%5E2%20%2B%20%28-9%20-%2061%20E%5E2%29%20z%20%2B%204%20%2812%20%2B%2037%20E%5E2%29%29%2F%28%289%20%2B%2052%20E%5E2%20%2B%2023%20E%5E4%29%20z%5E2%20%2B%204%20%28-12%20-%2031%20E%5E2%20%2B%20E%5E4%29%20z%20%2B%208%20E%5E2%20%28E%5E2%20-%201%29%29%2C%20%7Bz%2C%20-10%20-%2010%20I%2C%2010%20%2B%2010%20I%7D%5D)
>
> [image]

---

Play around with any order you need. To me, 2/2 is good enough.